# Regular Expression - Match End if Start is Match

Tags: c#, sql, .net, regex, t-sql

I want to match the following strings:

```
[anything can be here]
[{anything can be here}]
```

Can I achieve this using only one regular expression?

I am currently using this one `'^\[({)?.+(})?]$'`, but it will match also:

```
[anything can be here}]
[{anything can be here]
```

I need to to match `}` only if `{` is used.

Please, note I can use only regular expression match function as I have implemented it as `SQL CLR` function in order to use it in `T-SQL` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working: `\[[^{].*[^}]\]|\[\{.*\}\]`

**EDIT**
*as pointed out by OP something needs to be between parentheses so a 'one or more' match is more suited:*

`\[[^{].+[^}]\]|\[\{.+\}\]`

[see RegEx example here](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1vQ9/1)

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can write (verbatim strings):

```
^\[(?:{.+}|[^]{}]+)]$
```

You can use something more complicated with a conditional statement `(?(condition)then|else)`:

```
^\[({)?[^]{}]+(?(1)}|)]$
```

*(if capture group 1 exists, then `}` else nothing)*

But this way is probably less efficient.

Comment: You do not even need `|` in the conditional statement, just `^\[({)?[^]{}]+(?(1)})]$` is enough (with yes part only).

Comment: @stribizhev: Indeed, it's only to illustrate the conditional structure. But as I said using this way is overkill, it's only for information.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex `^\[({)?.+(})?]$` will match only an individual string like `[{...}]` or `[{...]` because 1) you have anchors (`^$`), and both curly braces are present in the same pattern.

I suggest using negative look-behinds to avoid matching strings that have just 1 curly brace inside the `[]`-ed string like this:

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"((?!\[\{[^}]+\]|\[[^{]+\})\[\{?.+?\}?\])");
var tst = "[anything can be here] [{anything can be here}] [anything can be here}] [{anything can be here]";
var mtch = rgx.Matches(tst).Cast<Match>().ToList();
```

This will make sure you match the `[]`-ed strings even in larger context.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`\[[^{].*[^}]\]|\[[^{}]\]|\[\{.+\}\]`

Which when broken down matches 3 types of string:

1. `[]` surrounding ≥ 2 characters provided the first character isn't `{` and the last character isn't `}`
2. `[{}]` surrounding anything
3. `[]` surrounding a single non curly brace character (an edge case not covered by previous answers)

Comment: I do not think it works appropriately. It is 1) too greedy, 2) matches unwanted cases. See http://goo.gl/9dlTyX

Answer (score 0):

Okay I know this question has been answered, but I thought I'd show a pure T-SQL solution just as an alternative.

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (val VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @yourTable
    VALUES  ('[anything can be here]'),
            ('[{anything can be here}]'),
            ('[anything can be here}]'),
            ('[{anything can be here]');

WITH CTE_Brackets
AS
(
    SELECT  val,
            CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('{',val) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('{',val)
            END  AS L_curly,
            CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('}',val) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('}',val)
            END AS R_curly,

            CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('[',val) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('[',val)
            END  AS L_bracket,
            CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX(']',val) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX(']',val)
            END  AS R_bracket
    FROM @yourTable
),
CTE_string
AS
(
    SELECT  val,
            L_curly,
            R_curly,
            L_bracket,
            R_bracket,
            SUBSTRING(val,start_pos,end_pos - start_pos) val_string
    FROM CTE_Brackets A
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT COALESCE(L_curly,L_bracket) + 1 AS start_pos,
                        COALESCE(R_curly,R_bracket)     AS end_pos
                ) CA
)

SELECT A.val,B.val
FROM CTE_string A
INNER JOIN CTE_string B
    ON A.val_string = B.val_string
    AND
    (
        (
                    A.L_curly IS NOT NULL
                AND A.R_curly IS NULL
                AND B.L_curly IS NULL
                AND B.R_curly IS NOT NULL
        ) --left curly matching right only curly
        OR 
        (
                    A.L_curly + A.R_curly IS NOT NULL
                AND B.R_curly IS NULL
                AND B.L_curly IS NULL
        ) --matches both curly to no curly
    )
ORDER BY B.val
```